# How to debug Blazor WASM inside iframe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, debugging, blazor, webassembly

When Blazor WASM is hosted by ASP.NET Core and resides inside iframe, the debugger doesn't work.
For example, I have Page1 with following html:

```
<app>Loading...</app>
<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

and Page2, which puts Page1 into iframe:

```
<iframe src="/Page1" width="800" height="600">
</iframe>
```

In this case:

- if Page1 is opened app and debugger work as inspected.
- If Page2 is opened, app works perfectly, but debugger doesn't: breakpoints are not working. Chromium dev tool debugging doesn't work too with error:

```
No inspectable pages found
The list of targets returned by http://127.0.0.1:9222/json contains no entries matching the URL https://localhost:44329/.
Make sure your browser is displaying the target application.
```

http://127.0.0.1:9222/json:

```
[ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/8B7C4E90151A1A8A3F9D2D8FD93130D6",
   "id": "8B7C4E90151A1A8A3F9D2D8FD93130D6",
   "title": "New Tab",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "http://127.0.0.1:9222/json",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/8B7C4E90151A1A8A3F9D2D8FD93130D6"
}, {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/DD0B85D174E30BF9E688213D52A312BD",
   "id": "DD0B85D174E30BF9E688213D52A312BD",
   "title": "127.0.0.1:52977/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44329%2F",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "http://127.0.0.1:52977/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44329%2F",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/DD0B85D174E30BF9E688213D52A312BD"
}, {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/CD68FDE522F1DCDE6D3B49DF4872CE26",
   "faviconUrl": "https://localhost:44329/favicon.ico",
   "id": "CD68FDE522F1DCDE6D3B49DF4872CE26",
   "title": "BlazorApp",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "https://localhost:44329/Frame",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/CD68FDE522F1DCDE6D3B49DF4872CE26"
}, {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/6D57386F9C6D65737DF416657993C190",
   "id": "6D57386F9C6D65737DF416657993C190",
   "title": "McAfee DLP Endpoint Chrome Extension",
   "type": "background_page",
   "url": "chrome-extension://hddjhjcbioambdhjejhdlobijkdnbggp/_generated_background_page.html",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/6D57386F9C6D65737DF416657993C190"
} ]
```

Repository with minimum code to reproduce: https://github.com/GTmAster/blazor-iframe-debug

**How to debug Blazor WASM, which is hosted inside iframe?**

Comment: I am also interested in this topic. Any progress or hints from elsewhere?

Comment: @borys86 It's planned for discussion in the next sprint by asp.net core team: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25958

Comment: I have a similar issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107680/how-to-debug-embedded-blazor-webassembly-application
I do not know how to debug embedded blazor app. Chrome seems unable to attach a debugger.

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand the underlying things, nor what changes the Microsoft/Blazor team might have made, but as for now, you don't need to make any additional changes on your launchSettings.json, when in Chrome, just fire your blazor url, then press Shift+Cmd+D (in Mac), a tab page will opened with develop tools opened automatically, there you can find all your C# components/code to debug.

Enjoy.